# Confusing icons/favicons

Tags: icons

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7guP.png)People say that you can make an icon for a website tab simply with `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/bookIcon.ico">` but whenever I do that it doesn't show anything up in the tab, just the default earth symbol (I'm using chrome, that may be it) and the title.

Comment: Have you actually made an image? Also it should be named favicon.ico and be in your webroot.

Comment: Yeah, the image is bookIcon.ico, and I think it is in the webroot

Comment: i would add it to the post but it's a .ico so not supported
plus it's 16x16 so it wouldn't really be visible in detail

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured it out: the file wasn't in the "img" folder. oof.